# Using an insertion sort to sort a doubly linked list C++

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to sort a doubly linked list with an insertion sort from the greatest value to lowest value. However, the insertion sort is not working and the program crashes if I use it. Using an insertion sort for a doubly linked list is very confusing to me, so I appreciate any help I can get.

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    T item;
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> next;
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> prev;

public:
    T getItem() { return item; }
   shared_ptr<Node<T>>& getNext() { return next; }
   shared_ptr<Node<T>>& getPrev() { return prev; }
}
```

This is the insertion sort that causes crashes. Could I not be swapping the nodes correctly?

```
void insertionSort()
    {
        shared_ptr<Node<T>> curPtr = top;
        shared_ptr<Node<T>> temp;
        shared_ptr<Node<T>> rover;

        while (curPtr != nullptr)
        {
            temp = curPtr;
            rover = curPtr->getPrev();

            while (rover != nullptr && temp->getItem() > rover->getItem())
            {

                rover = rover->getNext()->getNext();
                rover = rover->getPrev();
            }

            rover->getNext()->getNext() = temp;
            curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What crash are you experiencing? In which line?

Comment: Just FYI this is all super-inefficient due to the shared pointers being copied around and `getItem()` returning by value.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy it crashes at this line `rover->getNext()->getNext() = temp;`

Comment: @Mark - what if rover->getNext() is NULL?